# Rails 4 handling locale error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, locale, rails-i18n

Good Day everyone,

I am using Rails 4 and in my website, I am using the following links to handle locale:

> en - http://www.sample.com/XXXXX
>   zh-HK - http://www.sample.com/zh-HK/XXXXX
>   zh-CN - http://www.sample.com/zh-CN/XXXXX

Moreover, I am using the custom error page method to handle 404, 422 and 500 errors.
i.e.

config/routes.rb

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|zh-CN|zh-HK/ do
  root 'home#index'
  get '/' => 'home#index', as: :home_page
  get 'about' => 'home#about', as: :about_page
end

%w( 404 422 500 ).each do |code|
  get code, :to => "errors#show", :code => code
end

get '/:locale' => 'home#index'
```

config/environment/production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.exceptions_app = self.routes
end
```

app/controller/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

app/controller/errors_controller.rb

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    render status_code.to_s, :status => status_code, :layout => false
  end

protected

  def status_code
    params[:code] || 500
  end

end
```

****************Here is my problem.******************
When I type wrong link in a pattern like http://www.sample.com/zh-HK/abc,
it can show me the custom error page.

However when I type wrong link like e.g. http://www.sample.com/abc
(without locale (actually it should be the default locale :en) ),
this will not go to my custom error page.
Instead, it give me an error page like this:
[image: Not my custom error page]

How can I fix this so that when it is using default locale (that's mean no locale in link), it can use the custom error page? Thank you!

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try redirect all your not-matching routes to default locale like this:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|zh-CN|zh-HK/ do
  root 'home#index'
  get '/' => 'home#index', as: :home_page
  get 'about' => 'home#about', as: :about_page
end

%w( 404 422 500 ).each do |code|
  get code, :to => "errors#show", :code => code
end

root to: redirect("/en", status: 302), as: :redirected_root
get "/*path",
  to: redirect("/en/%{path}", status: 302),
  constraints: {path: /(?!(en|zh-CN|zh-HK)})\/).*/},
  format: false
```